# Проблема с microsoft azure AD

Tags: javascript, c#, active-directory, azure, sharepoint

Здравствуйте, начну с того что я новичок в работе с ms azure, но у меня на работе появилась следующая задача, при помощи azure AD получить список пользователей из Sharepoint и их свойства. Желательно без использования кода (для админа) но не обязательно.

Azure AD и Sharepoint синхронизированы, но когда я пытаюсь получить (вернуть)  информацию о пользователях ничего не получается.

Comment: Вам нужно получить список пользователей из SharePoint? Пожалуйста, уточните.

Comment: Да у меня есть пользователи в SP, и мне нужно подтянуть их в Azure, я читал что необходимо воспользоваться Токеном каким-то для этого а это невозможно в базовой версии Azure.

Comment: SharePoint облачный? И я правильно понял, что пользователи заполнили свои профили в SharePoint и вы хотите эти данные чтобы в AD ушли, верно?

Comment: Извините что долго не отвечал, да пользователи заполнили свои профили в SP и я хочу чтобы они ушли в AD.

Answer (score 0):

Итак, судя по комментарию к вопросу — задача в том, чтобы данные из службы профилей SharePoint перенести в Active Directory. AD размещена в Azure.

Сделать это можно используя Powershell.
Информация, о том как работать с Azure AD через Powershell, [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/jj151815.aspx). Вам надо обновлять нужные поля.
Но перед этим необходимо [получить](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29415.export-sharepoint-online-user-profile-information-using-powershell-csom.aspx) нужные значения из SharePoint Online.